# ofstream and ifstream path works writing not reading in C++ Builder

Tags: c++, c++builder

I can create a text file as follows using ofstream, to the specified path:

```
std::string path = "c:\users\john\file.txt";
std::string str = "some text";

ofstream myfile;
myfile.open (path);
myfile << str; // write string to text file
myfile.close();    //close file
```

---

When I try to open/read the file the system seems to open the file but throws the "no data found" exception here...even though the file is there and contains the text.

---

```
std::string line = "";
std::string str = "";
std::string path = "c:\users\john\file.txt";

ifstream file (path);  
if (file.is_open())
{
   while ( getline (file,line) )
   {
      str = str + line;
   }

   file.close();

   if (str == "")
   {
      throw(Exception("Error: No data found..."));
   }
}

else

throw(Exception("Error: File not found..."));
```

---

This only seems to happen when trying to read from some location other than the debug folder...

So if I can create the file in the user directory why can't I read it??

Can anyone help?

UPDATE:

I just discovered that if the write function is run and the read function is run right after that with the app still running it works.  If however the write function is run then the app closed and reopened the read function then fails as described above.

Comment: Shouldn't this be `std::string str="some text";` ?

Comment: `std::string path = "c:\users\john\file.txt";` should be `std::string path = "c:\\users\\john\\file.txt";` Also you never check if `myfile.open (path);` worked when writing.

Comment: What is getline? The lack of the std:: prefix when you use it for other stl constructs is making me wonder if it is std::getline or something custom.  There could be a bug hiding there.

Comment: @JeremiahB I doubt so, OP probably used `using namespace std;`

Comment: yes that was a typo, sorry...

Comment: @Jim What typo? Missing `std::` or missing `str`?

Comment: I added std::getline -- no change...

Comment: missing string...but both were changed... still same problems...

Comment: @Jim _"still same problems... "_ So my answer didn't fix your problem?? You must be doing something wrong elsewhere and didn't show that in your code example.

Answer (score 0):

Use a single forward slash (/) instead.

Writing operations on text files are performed in the same way we operated with cout:

```
// writing on a text file
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main () {
  ofstream myfile ("example.txt");
  if (myfile.is_open())
  {
    myfile << "This is a line.\n";
    myfile << "This is another line.\n";
    myfile.close();
  }
  else cout << "Unable to open file";
  return 0;
}
```

Reading from a file can also be performed in the same way that we did with cin:

```
// reading a text file
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main () {
  string line;
  ifstream myfile ("example.txt");
  if (myfile.is_open())
  {
    while ( getline (myfile,line) )
    {
      cout << line << '\n';
    }
    myfile.close();
  }

  else cout << "Unable to open file"; 

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: How does that address the problem the OP describes?

Comment: Seen that, not essentially better.

Comment: just discovered the program is clearing the file out when it runs ....  some other problem having nothing to do with the read op...

Answer (score 0):

Your writing code fails silently, you should change that to

```
std::string path = "c:\users\john\file.txt";
std::string str = "some text";

ofstream myfile;
myfile.open (path);
if(myfile.is_open()) // <<<<<<<
    myfile << str; // write string to text file
}
else {
    std::cout << "Cannot open file." << std::endl;
}
myfile.close();    //close file
```

Your primary problem is that backslashes in string literals need to be escaped:

```
std::string path = "c:\\users\\john\\file.txt";
                   // ^      ^     ^
```

so the file couldn't be opened for writing at all, and you didn't notice that, because your code never checked about it.

Comment: Probably worth tossing in a note about checking the `myfile << str` for success as well.

Comment: @user4581301 Sure, if the file couldn't be opened, that will also fail.